# What's the difference between 快 and 快要?

Tags: usage, difference

I started to learn Chinese like one month ago and I'm facing a first misunderstanding.

In my book it says that `快` can be used to say *"soon"* but `快要` is also used to express the same thing. Is there a difference or I can use both in every situation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There isn't really a difference in the two if you are using it to mean *"soon"*, except that `快要` is more formal than `快`.

For example:

> 他快死了。
>
> 他快要死了。

Both mean:

> He is dying soon.

`快` is just a shorten form of `快要` when used in such context and it is quite commonly used in speech.

Comment: Note: The sentence final `了` is pretty much required.

Answer (score 2):

For me it's also a matter of emphasis. I feel when used to mean "soon", 快要 is more emphatic than 快.

For example, in the Chinese version of "If you keep doing that, I'm going to go nuts soon", I would prefer to use 快要 to emphasize that I'm going to go nuts soon.

But this is no different from English where people use formality for emphasis. For example, a mother might call her daughter Lucille when she's angry at her but call her Lucy when she's not.

Answer (score 2):

You can ignore the difference between them when they are used in front of a verb in a sentence. Otherwise we can say "快了" but not "快要了". For example, when asked "他什么时候来？”，one can say "快了" but cannot say "快要了”